# netlify deploy problems with bot

Tags: node.js, netlify

I'm building a whatssap bot and i'm deploying on netlify, but when i deploy works but steals with the status of "building", but in reality it's already working, so how can i change the status?

i've tried deploy on vercel, but i got the same

my netlify.toml is this way

```
[build] 
base = "."
command = "node src/index.js"
publish = "./build/"
```

i don't know why this is happen, maybe i need to put a dist location, but i'm not sure